# Are names of query variables in SPARQL case-sensivite?

Tags: sparql, jena

Are [variable names](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#QSynVariables) in SPARQL queries case-sensitive? E.g., will variables `?abc` and `?ABC` (within a given scope) always refer to the same variable?

If the answer can only be given in relation to a specific implementation, I'm most interested in the current version of Jena (ARQ).

Comment: Although I don't know sparql, Before asking such a question I would test it or research online...did you do that ?

Comment: @Bartdude Of course I did. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Well, if you did test you probably have your answer by now... so asking the question here lets me think you didn't. You wouldn't believe how many questions of that kind we see here :-)

Comment: @Bartude What I was (am) looking for is a specification in addition to the empirical evidence from an implementation. Those things are normally written down, but I didn't see this addressed anywhere in the standard. Hence my question.

Comment: plus one Because this is a legitimate question, and Drux is right:  while the SPARQL grammar lays out the syntax of variables, it doesn't explicitly say whether variables are case sensitive or not, just that, e.g., `?foo` and `?FOO` are both variable names, and that "use of a given variable name anywhere in a query identifies the same variable."  But what equality relationship is used to determine whether two names are the same?  In this case, it's case-sensitive, but that's not stated explicitly.

Comment: This is especially confused by the fact that other keywords and function names (e.g., `select`, `fIlTeR`, `ValUES`, etc.) are *not* case sensitive in SPARQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the variables are case sensitive. `?abc` and `?ABC` are surely different. They do not map to same bindings for the query.

Comment: Can you link to (or cite) a reference please?

Comment: @drux - you can look in the SPARQL query spec at the grammar.

Comment: @AndyS The grammar seems to imply case-sensitivity for variables, because (unlike for keywords) it does not mention the opposite. Is this correct or did I miss an explicit statement in relation to variables?

Comment: Why should the names "abc" and "ABC" be *surely different*?  The default behavior in some programming languages would be to treat them as the same, and `select` and `SELECT` aren't *surely different* in SPARQL.  *Most* of SPARQL is case insensitive, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, variable names are case sensitive. This is not explicitly stated in the SPARQL specification, but is implied by the fact that everything that is *not* case sensitive (e.g. SPARQL keywords such as "SELECT") is explicitly stated to be so (so as you yourself remarked, it is implied by not mentioning the opposite).

All compliant SPARQL implementations that I know of, including Sesame, Jena, GraphDB, Stardog, Redland, dotNetRDF, etc. etc. implement variable names in this fashion.